# Which algorithm should I use to find the shortest path from A towards B in an unweighted grid?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

The scenario is a turn-based situation where the player has to move towards a location B from source location A, but can only move a maximum amount of units.

For example, B is 24 units away from A (calculated using BFS), and I've rolled a score of 12. How can I find the best path towards B that's only 12 movement-units away?

Notes:

- Can not move diagonally
- There are large obstacles

**Edit:** This is for a game similar to Clue / Cluedo, but is text-only so the player will choose a direction to move 'towards'.

Here is what I tried:

Example grid: (◘ is obstacle, ○ is not)

```
○○○○○○○○○○
○○○○○○○○◘◘
○○○◘◘◘○○◘◘
○○○◘◘◘○○B◘
○A○◘◘◘○○◘◘
```

Algorithm:

```
if paces == 0, return
try moving col closer to dest.col:
    if col == dest.col, move row closer to dest.row
    else if adjacent is blocked, move row away from start
```

This works okay on paper, except for when I run myself into a corner:

```
○A→◘◘○○◘◘◘
○○↓◘◘○○B◘◘
○○↓◘◘○○◘◘◘
○○↓◘◘○○↑◘◘
○○↓→→→→→◘◘
```

**Solution:**

```
public ArrayList<Location> shortestPath(final Location start, final Location dest) {
    HashSet<Location> visits = new HashSet<>();
    HashMap<Location, Location> links = new HashMap<>();

    PriorityQueue<Location> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Board.GRID_COLS * Board.GRID_ROWS,
            new Comparator<Location>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(Location a, Location b) {
                    return Integer.compare(getHeuristic(a, dest), getHeuristic(b, dest));
                }
            });

    queue.add(start);

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Location current = queue.remove();
        if (current.equals(dest)) {
            ArrayList<Location> path = reconstruct(current, new LinkedList<Location>(), links);
            path.add(dest);
            return path;
        }

        visits.add(current);
        for (Location neighbour : getNeighbours(current)) {
            if (!visits.contains(neighbour)) {
                queue.add(neighbour);
                visits.add(neighbour);
                links.put(neighbour, current);
            }
        }

    }
    return null; // failed
}

// Manhattan distance
private int getHeuristic(Location src, Location dest) {
    return Math.abs(dest.row - src.row) + Math.abs(dest.col - src.col);
}

private ArrayList<Location> reconstruct(Location current, LinkedList<Location> list, HashMap<Location, Location> links) {
    if (links.containsKey(current)) {
        list.addFirst(links.get(current));
        return reconstruct(links.get(current), list, links);
    } else {
        return new ArrayList<>(list);
    }
}

private ArrayList<Location> getNeighbours(Location current) {
    ArrayList<Location> neighbours = new ArrayList<>();

    if (current.row < GRID_ROWS - 1) {
        Location n = LOCATIONS[current.row + 1][current.col];
        if (isAccessible(n, current)) neighbours.add(n);
    }
    if (current.row > 0) {
        Location n = LOCATIONS[current.row - 1][current.col];
        if (isAccessible(n, current)) neighbours.add(n);
    }
    if (current.col < GRID_COLS - 1) {
        Location n = LOCATIONS[current.row][current.col + 1];
        if (isAccessible(n, current)) neighbours.add(n);
    }
    if (current.col > 0) {
        Location n = LOCATIONS[current.row][current.col - 1];
        if (isAccessible(n, current)) neighbours.add(n);

    }
    return neighbours;
}
```

Comment: Is taking the shortest path between A and B and going those 12 units not enough?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Comment: (Also, I assume you mean maximum, not minimum)

Comment: Search the web for "path finding algorithm". Which algorithm is best depends on a lot of factors that you have not specified. (@DennisMeng - Following the shortest path can be a terrible strategy when there are obstacles.)

Comment: @mariusnn Is Dijkstra's any different from BFS in an unweighted graph?

Comment: @TedHopp Ah okay, noted.

Comment: @TedHopp I have been searching and of course I've come across all the widely-used ones, but they all seem to be applied to weighted graphs.

Comment: @DennisMeng The problem with BFS is that I don't know how to backtrack once I've found the destination.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you memoize and store how far everything is from A, you can backtrack, but ideally you'd change how you implement edges to allow for optimizations.

Comment: @DennisMeng I would like to avoid that, and I'm sure it's possible. I came close but didn't notice a massive flaw in my algorithm. I'll post what I tried.

Comment: If it applies to weighted graphs, it applies to unweighted graphs as well.  Just set all the weights to 1.

Comment: Just FYI, if you add `neighbor` to `visits` as soon as you enqueue it, you won't need to check `queue.contains(neighbour)`, which should drastically speed up your algorithm, since `PriorityQueue.contains()` is an O(n) method.  Also, if you need a bit more speed, you can eliminate `visits` altogether if you add a `HasBeenVisited` property to your `Location` class *(or, more usually, have an internal `Node<T>` class that has that property)*

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Thanks, that makes sense and I've updated the solution in my question in case anyone would ever like to learn something from it. However I disagree with eliminating visits, as adding an extra field to `Location` only to accommodate a single algorithm seems unnecessary when `HashSet` has constant time `add` and `contains`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect job for [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm).

On your graph, it will basically just be the same (algorithmically) as breadth-first search, but using a priority-queue *(ordered by `f(x)`)* rather than a queue.

Answer (score 1):

Some useful comments, the top-left corner of the game board should be coordinates (0, 0). You can choose any returned paths in case you are interested in to know only one path. The optimum steps is the length of the path - 1 because the path includes the starting point. Hopefully will it helps you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Game
{
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Find a matrix with all possible optimum paths from point A to point B in the game board
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="board">Game board</param>
        /// <param name="moves">Allowed moves</param>
        /// <param name="matrix">Resulting matrix</param>
        /// <param name="A">Point A</param>
        /// <param name="B">Point B</param>
        private static void FindMatrix(List<List<char>> board, List<Point> moves, out List<List<int>> matrix, out Point A, out Point B)
        {
            matrix = new List<List<int>>();
            A = new Point(-1, -1);
            B = new Point(-1, -1);
            //Init values of the matrix
            for (int row = 0; row < board.Count; row++)
            {
                matrix.Add(new List<int>());
                for (int col = 0; col < board[row].Count; col++)
                {
                    matrix[matrix.Count - 1].Add(board[row][col] == '◘' ? -1 : 0);
                    switch (board[row][col])
                    {
                        case 'A':
                            {
                                A.X = col;
                                A.Y = row;
                                matrix[row][col] = -1;
                                break;
                            }
                        case 'B':
                            {
                                B.X = col;
                                B.Y = row;
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            if ((A.X >= 0) && (A.Y >= 0) && (B.X >= 0) && (B.Y >= 0)) //To check if points A and B exist in the board
            {
                var pairs = new List<Point>[2] { new List<Point>(), new List<Point>() };
                int index = 0;
                int level = 0;
                pairs[index].Add(A);
                while ((pairs[index].Count > 0) && (pairs[index][pairs[index].Count - 1] != B))
                {
                    pairs[Math.Abs(1 - index)].Clear();
                    level++;
                    foreach (var pair in pairs[index])
                        foreach (var move in moves) //Test all possible moves
                            if ((pair.Y + move.Y >= 0) && (pair.Y + move.Y < board.Count) && (pair.X + move.X >= 0) && (pair.X + move.X < board[pair.Y + move.Y].Count) && (matrix[pair.Y + move.Y][pair.X + move.X] == 0)) //Inside the board? Not visited before?
                            {
                                pairs[Math.Abs(1 - index)].Add(new Point(pair.X + move.X, pair.Y + move.Y));
                                matrix[pair.Y + move.Y][pair.X + move.X] = level;
                            }
                    index = Math.Abs(1 - index);
                }
                matrix[A.Y][A.X] = 0;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds all possible optimum paths from point A to point B in the game board matix
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="matrix">Game board matrix</param>
        /// <param name="moves">Allowed moves</param>
        /// <param name="A">Point A</param>
        /// <param name="B">Point B</param>
        /// <param name="result">Resulting optimum paths</param>
        /// <param name="list">Temporary single optimum path</param>
        private static void WalkMatrix(List<List<int>> matrix, List<Point> moves, Point A, Point B, ref List<List<Point>> result, ref List<Point> list)
        {
            if ((list.Count > 0) && (list[list.Count - 1] == B)) //Stop condition
            {
                result.Add(new List<Point>(list));
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var move in moves)
                    if ((A.Y + move.Y >= 0) && (A.Y + move.Y < matrix.Count) && (A.X + move.X >= 0) && (A.X + move.X < matrix[A.Y + move.Y].Count) && (matrix[A.Y + move.Y][A.X + move.X] == matrix[A.Y][A.X] + 1)) //Inside the board? Next step?
                    {
                        list.Add(new Point(A.X + move.X, A.Y + move.Y)); //Store temporary cell
                        WalkMatrix(matrix, moves, list[list.Count - 1], B, ref result, ref list);
                        list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1); //Clean temporary cell
                    }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds all possible optimum paths from point A to point B in the game board
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="board">Game board</param>
        /// <returns>All possible optimum paths</returns>
        public static List<List<Point>> FindPaths(List<List<char>> board)
        {
            var result = new List<List<Point>>();
            var moves = new List<Point> { new Point(1, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(-1, 0), new Point(0, -1) }; //Right, Down, Left, Up (clockwise)
            List<List<int>> matrix; //Matrix temporary representation of the game to store all possible optimum paths
            Point A;
            Point B;
            FindMatrix(board, moves, out matrix, out A, out B);
            if ((A.X >= 0) && (A.Y >= 0) && (B.X >= 0) && (B.Y >= 0)) //To check if points A and B exist in the board
            {
                List<Point> list = new List<Point>();
                list.Add(A);
                WalkMatrix(matrix, moves, A, B, ref result, ref list);
            }
            return result;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<char>> board = new List<List<char>> //An example of game board
            {
                new List<char>("○○○○○○○○○○"),
                new List<char>("○○○○○○○○◘◘"),
                new List<char>("○○○◘◘◘○○◘◘"),
                new List<char>("○○○◘◘◘○○B◘"),
                new List<char>("○A○◘◘◘○○◘◘")
            };
            List<List<Point>> paths = FindPaths(board);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me figure out how to implement it. :) +1